# `serie: true` cannot ensure loading order of modules

Tags: angularjs, codemirror, oclazyload

I want to load `CodeMirror` by `ocLazyLoad`. Since `xml.min.js`, `htmlmixed.min.js`, `css.min.js`, etc. all need `codemirror.min.js` to be loaded before them. I try to use `serie: true` to make sure the loading order:

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    debug: true,
    serie: true,
    modules: [{ 
        name : 'codeMirror1', 
        files: [
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/codemirror.min.css",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/codemirror.min.js"
    ]},{
        name : 'codeMirror2',
        files: [
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.min.js",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/css/css.min.js",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-codemirror/0.3.0/ui-codemirror.min.js"
    ]}]
});

$stateProvider
    .state('site', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        resolve: {
            loadSiteCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(['codeMirror1', 'codeMirror2'])
            }]
        },
    })
```

However, the above code still returns:

```
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/codemirror.min.css
xml.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
    at xml.min.js:1
    at xml.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ xml.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ xml.min.js:1
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js
htmlmixed.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
    at htmlmixed.min.js:1
    at htmlmixed.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ htmlmixed.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ htmlmixed.min.js:1
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.min.js
css.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
    at css.min.js:1
    at css.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ css.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ css.min.js:1
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/css/css.min.js
javascript.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
    at javascript.min.js:1
    at javascript.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ javascript.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ javascript.min.js:1
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-codemirror/0.3.0/ui-codemirror.min.js
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.componentLoaded (3) ["ui.codemirror", "constant", "uiCodemirrorConfig"]
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.componentLoaded (3) ["ui.codemirror", "directive", "uiCodemirror"]
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.moduleLoaded ui.codemirror
angular.js:13920 ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/codemirror.min.js
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Check the sequence of `codemirror.js` that is being added. Its getting called before it has been added.

Comment: As the log shows, `codemirror.min.js` is indeed loaded the last, which is not what `$ocLazyLoadProvider.config` defines by `serie: true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the `serie` option to the provider configuration object, [which is ignored](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/blob/master/src/ocLazyLoad.loaders.core.js#L146) since it will get the config for each module and load them in parallel anyways. Basically that option needs to be present on *every* module which scripts need to be loaded in order.

A quick solution for you is to make use of promises to make sure modules are loaded in order. Since the `load()` call returns a promise, we can execute a second load after that:

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    debug: true,
    modules: [{ 
        name : 'codeMirror1', 
        files: [
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/codemirror.min.css",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/codemirror.min.js"
    ]},{
        name : 'codeMirror2',
        files: [
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.min.js",
            ...
    ]}]
});

...
loadSiteCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
    return $ocLazyLoad.load(['codeMirror1']).then(function() {
      return $ocLazyLoad.load(['codeMirror2'])
    });
}]
...
```

Check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y00Pvv56MF3gHBGOkpi6) for a working example of this.

Alternatively, since `CodeMirror` [supports module loaders](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modloader) and `ocLazyLoad` [plays nicely with `requireJS`](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/tree/master/examples/requireJSExample) you might be interested on trying it. You would set `requireJS` as the loader for modules on `ocLazyLoad` and, when loading the modules that depend on 
`CodeMirror`, it would make sure they were already loaded (meaning you wouldn't need to do things in series).

Comment: Thank you... But I want to load all the `.js` except `codemirror.min.js` at the same time. That's the reason why I made 2 modules.

Comment: Check my edited answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating modules for different libraries try this method and see if it works because it is running fine for me:

```
resolve: {
  plugins: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/codemirror.min.css",
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/codemirror.min.js",
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js",
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.min.js",
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/css/css.min.js",
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.36.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js",
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-codemirror/0.3.0/ui-codemirror.min.js"
    ]);
  }]
}
```